# Set custom domain for cookies with Google IAP

Tags: cookies, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam, google-iap

I'm using [Google Cloud IAP](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/) (Identity Aware Proxy) to restrict access to several services running on different subdomains (`a.mycompany.com`, `b.mycompany.com`, etc.).

When I log in to `a.mycompany.com`, I'd like it to log me in to `b.mycompany.com` as well. When I authenticate via one of these URLs, I see this `set-cookie` header on the final redirect:

```
set-cookie: GCP_IAAP_AUTH_TOKEN=eyJh...HsA; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
```

My understanding is that I could share this cookie by [adding a domain=](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain) clause to it. Is it possible to do this with GCP IAP?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to manually update the headers that IAP uses, it seems like a black box. I'd suggest you to submit a feature request via this [link](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) under "Identity & Security".

Answer (score 0):

It seems that GCP IAP supports a `cookieDomain` property that you could use to share the cookie between your two sub-domains:

https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/reference/rest/v1/IapSettings